# Creating a scalable knowledge graph

Tags: jena, ontology

I have been reading lots of resources and this is what I learnt so far is required to create a knowledge graph:

1. Use extraction techniques to get entities and relationships such as Named Entity Recognition
2. Try to use existing vocabualaries to map data
3. Use embedding techniques such as TransE to find relationships within the KG
4. Use of triple stores such as Apache Jena to store the data in Turtle or other formats
5. Use SPARQL server to query data

My question is if a user needs to input new data for ex: using the FOAF person one might be including the name and surname of a person from the available data but not the image. If a user has an image of that person how is it possible without manual intervention to include that image in the triple store and map it with an ontology?

Comment: By image you meant a picture ? If I assume that image will be stored some where in another storage (s3,NoSQL). The whats stopping you to  add triple with that stored image id